# How to have html elements lay over and reach out of CSS "column"

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, multiple-columns, absolute

What I need is a 2 column based layout with content that loads dynamically and distributes evenly over as much space as it needs.

So I thought CSS columns is the perfect fit. It is for the case stated above **but** the content is not plain text it's actually input elements with potential dropdowns, for which I am using twitter's typeahead.

But this dropdown, should of course be ignored by the column mechanism and is supposed to lay over the columns and maybe even stick out of it.

Here is an image to illustrate the desired effect:
[image]

I assumed that absolut positioning of the nested div would do it, with no luck. Is there any way to do this kind of magic without JS?

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="text"/>
        <div class="dropdown"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

```css
fieldset {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

check out the pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByJXVW

Comment: In order to share your codepen you'll need to hit the save button to generate a url. The given link leads to the 'create new code' page.

Answer (score 0):

Update: could it be you had it already working? I have just added a background color, to make it visible.

```css
fieldset {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
}

.ontop {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <div class="item">List Item1         
        <div class="ontop"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">List Item2</div>
    <div class="item">List Item3</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: No. Actually not at all. The div "onTop" which is supposed to "lay over" the columns needs to be nested inside the "item" and should cover elements below it. Like a dropdown would do. The pen should work now.

Comment: You might have to refresh this page. Just double checked with colleague. Pen is working. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByJXVW

Comment: strange, it isn't loading for me. Anyway i updated my answer.

Comment: The overlays do cover the other input elements in the fieldset, but they are supposed to "stick out of the column based fieldset" and should completely ignore the column. If you remove the "relative" positioning from the "item", you get the desired effect, just that the positing is off.

Comment: and you do need to put a vendor prefix (-webkit- for example) in front of the column-count and gap. I removed them for the sake of simplicity of the codesnipplet.

Comment: Thanks. Still I don't quite get it yet. The dropdown should overlay the inputs, or push them down?

Comment: It is supposed to overlay the inputs but also it should not affect the size of the fieldset or the order of the input items. if you give it a significant higher hight, or remove them completely you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Okay now i got it, but i dont think there will be a css only solution. As you will be using twitter's typeahead I'd suggest you place one dropdown-div outside the fieldset and set ´display:none´ when it is not needed. Set `display:static` and the absolute position when it's nedded. I would use that one div for all inputs (as long as you will be showing only one at the time).

Comment: on the otherside, let that fancy css column stuff away and use some old school "width 50%" and you could reach your goal, or even better flexbox. :D Would you consider that?

Comment: I considered both but the content should read from top to bottom and then continue on the right side. And flexbox doesn't help either as I don't have a fixed height for the whole container because I don't know how much items it contains. Check out the image I just uploaded in the initial post. On top the items might vary in height and width. But I am open for any suggestions.